# How did || come to be used in crypto texts to represent concatenation?

Tags: nist, standards, notation, literature

In [RFC5647](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5647), [NIST SP 800-38D](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf#page=18), etc., `||` is used to denote concatenation. How did that come to be?

In most programming languages `||` represents "or" and `+` denotes concatenation and the fact that crypto texts just kind of mixed it up seems to make for an easy gotcha.

Comment: Don't remember how it started to appears in articles, however, using plus was confusing with math plus if you don't carefully look at the notation of the articles.

Comment: I'd argue that it's programming languages that use weird notation. The symbol for logical or has as far as I can tell always been $\lor$. So there isn't really any confusion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The origin is set theory and not programming languages.  In the context of cryptography, I could describe a set that is 
$$x_1 \parallel x_2 \parallel \dots \parallel x_n$$
as a concatenation of the series described by
$$\parallel_{i=1}^n x_i.$$
Furthermore, it's worth noting that `+` to a mathematician would suggest that it is a commutative, which might not be true depending on the set (as we could have a set of functions).

Comment: While I agree that the notation comes [from mathematics](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Concatenation.html), I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "a set that is [...] a concatenation sum". I've seen $\|$ used to denote the concatenation of strings or tuples, such that if $a = (1,2)$ and $b = (3,4,5)$, then $a\,\|\,b = (1,2,3,4,5)$, and of course one can naturally [generalize this to _sets of_ strings or tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation#Concatenation_of_sets_of_strings), but I'm not sure if that's what you mean. Or what, if anything, rational numbers have to do with any of it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Good points, I will update the answer to reflect that.  I was being lazy as it's a holiday here.  The real numbers note was just me pointing to that cryptography uses numbers.  My work usually has concatenation of functions in a set; however, the set is bounded so I cannot just have general statements without something running out of the bounds.

Answer (score 9):

Some languages like [PL/I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I) and [Oracle Database SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database) indeed use `||` for string concatenation.

One reason is maybe that `+` might be confusing when talking about fundamental cryptography, since there is a lot of math involved. The mathematical notation for 'OR' would be reversed caret $\lor$ and the exclusive 'OR', better known as 'XOR' is a circled plus $\oplus$.

But I don't think that there is a specific reason for using `||` for a string concatenation. If anything then I would presume that someone used it once early and then it has become accustomed until it has become a standard for cryptography.